# Consulta SQL + média

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Senhores tenho uma consulta que faz o calculo por linha.

O resultado fica no campo `calculo_diff`.

O calculo é  a diferença `DataHoraTerno`,conforme figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Agora eu necessito fazer uma média do `calulo_diff`, conforme a descrição.

Ou seja, seria uma média de:

> Operando H. Norma
>
> Aguardando Carreta

Algume pode me ajudar?

```
SELECT      Descricao
        ,   DataHoraTerno
        ,   @linha          := TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(@DataHoraTerno, DataHoraTerno), '%H%i') AS calculo_diff
        ,   @DataHoraTerno  := DataHoraTerno                                                AS valor_aux
        ,   @voltas         := @voltas + 1                                                  AS voltas
FROM        EmbarqueNavio
        ,   (
                SELECT  @DataHoraTerno  := 0
                    ,   @voltas         := 0
            ) AS vars
WHERE       NavioViagem = 3
        AND Terno       = 1
ORDER BY    DataHoraTerno DESC
```

Comment: Ola @Arita, Bem vindo ao SOpt, e recomendo você postar o código ao invés da imagem dele, para isso clique em [Edit], não esqueça de fazer o [Tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT      X.Descricao
        ,   AVG(X.calculo_diff) AS Media
FROM        (
                SELECT      Descricao
                        ,   DataHoraTerno
                        ,   @linha          := TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(@DataHoraTerno, DataHoraTerno), '%H%i') AS calculo_diff
                        ,   @DataHoraTerno  := DataHoraTerno                                                AS valor_aux
                        ,   @voltas         := @voltas + 1                                                  AS voltas
                FROM        EmbarqueNavio
                        ,   (
                                SELECT  @DataHoraTerno  := 0
                                    ,   @voltas         := 0
                            ) AS vars
                WHERE       NavioViagem = 3
                        AND Terno       = 1
                ORDER BY    DataHoraTerno DESC
            ) X
GROUP BY    X.Descricao
```

Comment: João Martins muito obrigado pela sua atenção !!!

Funcionou perfeitamente !!!! 

Abração !!!!

Comment: De nada @AritaMarcelo! Marque a resposta como correta e aproveite e dê um UP!

Answer (score 0):

Estou imaginando que é isso que você quer:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| Descrição           | Média calculo_diff    |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| Operando H. Norma   |   15                  |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| Aguardando Carreta  |   20                  |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Se o campo `calculo_diff` não fosse um campo calculado, seria algo como:

```
SELECT Descricao, AVERAGE(calculo_diff) as media_calculo_diff FROM tabelanome 
GROUP BY Descricao;
```

No seu caso `tabelanome` poderia ser o resultado da consulta que você já faz.

Comment: Obrigado Juven_v sou leigo mas entendi sua sugestão.
Então o calculo_diff é gerado pelo SQL agora nao sei se vale a pena eu fazer uma rotina para que grave no banco esse calculo.... vou ter um trabalhão para fazer isso .. ou seja toda vez que o usuario cadastrar um novo horario vou ter que gravar no banco a diferença. 

Tentei pela sua opção mas esta dando erro ... 

tabelanome coloquei a rotina entre parênteses mas mesmo assim esta dando erro...